# How to do this line rotation (matrices) question?

Tags: matrices

Question: The line $y=10-2x$ is rotated anticlockwise about the origin such that its image has an $x$-intercept of $(p,0)$ and $y$-intercept of $(0,q)$. Determine the angle of rotation θ $(0 ≤ θ ≤ 90)$ such that $p=q$.

[image]

I know that i probably need to do this and possibly letting $x' = p$ and $y'=0$. But i dont know its original point $(x,y)$ so what should i do?

I can find the x/y  intercepts as well as the gradient of the line but does that help?

Comment: Look where are mapped the points $(x, 10-2x)$.

Comment: @MarcoLecci what do u mean? substituting the points into [x,y]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points $(5,0)$ and $(0,10)$ are the intercepts of the given line $y=10-2x$.

Let's find their images after being rotated by $t$ degrees counterclockwise around the origin:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\ \sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}5\cos t\\ 5\sin t\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ y_1\end{pmatrix}; \\
\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\ \sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 10\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-10\sin t\\ 10\cos t\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\ y_2\end{pmatrix}$$
The slope of the line passing through these two points must be $-1$ (Why? If not sure, see appendix.):
$$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=-1 \Rightarrow \frac{10\cos t-5\sin t}{-10\sin t-5\cos t}=-1\Rightarrow \tan t=\frac13 \Rightarrow t=\arctan \frac13=18.43^\circ. $$

Appendix:

> Because its intercepts are $(p,0)$ and $(0,p)$.

Comment: this is epic. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The line of cartesian equation $2x+y-10 = 0$ is having for direction the vector $u = (-1,2)$ and passes through the point $P=(5,0)$. *Do you see that?*

The rotated line has for direction the rotated vector and passes through the rotated point.

Compute those to find the equation of the rotated line based on the angle $\theta$.

Then find $\theta$ based on the condition $p=q$.

Comment: Sorry, i dont get the vector part, why did you choose -1?

Comment: @FredWeasley Because the vector coordinates satisfy the equation of the line without the constant term. And indeed $2 \times (-1) + 2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The image $(x',y')$ by this rotation of the generic point $(x,10-x)$ of the first line is : $$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\10-2x\end{pmatrix}$$

This image must belong to a line with this equation $x'+y'=p$ (for a certain constant $p$), **whatever $x$**.

Condition $x'+y'=p$ gives an expression $Ax+B=p$, which must be independent of $x$ ; thus we must have $A=0$.

This gives constraint $-\cos(\theta)+3\sin(\theta)=0$

From there, we deduce $\theta=$atan$(1/3)=0.3218 rad\approx 18.5 $ degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some geometry: if the line is rotated by an angle $\theta$, its normal vector is rotated likewise. Now, let $\varphi$ the polar angle of the given line – with cartesian equation $\;2x+y=10$. A normal vector is $(2,1), so $\;\varphi=\arctan\frac12$.

On the other hand, the polar angle of a normal angle to the rotated line, which has equation $x+y=p,\:$ is $\:\frac \pi4=\arctan 1$, so the angle of rotation is
$$\theta=\arctan 1-\arctan\tfrac12.$$
Can you end the computation?